# Oracle: Rank with condition and keeping history

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have this sample table:

[image]

I need to create a rank column that will order the id's based on is_true=1, meaning that every change in is_true from 0 to 1 will increase the index by 1.
Something like the following:

[image]

I tried something like:

```
select id, customer_id, is_true,  
       rank() over (partition by customer_id order by (case when is_true=1 then id end)) index_rank 
from table
```

but it does not give what I need.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a window sum:

```
select
    t.*,
    1 + sum(is_true) over(partition by cutsomer_id order by id) index_rank
from mytable t
```

If you want to allow consecutive `1`s without increasing the rank, then you can use `lag()` first:

```
select
    t.*,
    1 + sum(case when is_true = 1 and lag_is_true = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
        over(partition by cutsomer_id order by id) index_rank
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(is_true) over(partition by cutsomer_id order by id) lag_is_true
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: This could have a problem if you got two consecutive (1) in the is_true column?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph: yes could be. I updated my answer with a solution for that case.

Comment: This could also have issues if it starts with is_true=1

Answer (score 1):

**improving upon the query provided by GMB**

```
select x.*
       ,sum(case when (is_true=1 and lag_val=0) or (lag_val is null) then 1 end) over(partition by customer_id order by id) index_rank
  from (select *
               ,lag(is_true) over(partition by customer_id order by id) lag_val       
          from dbo.t 
        )x
```

**OLD Query**

```
select id
       ,customer_id
       ,is_true
       ,dense_rank() over(partition by customer_id order by customer_id,max_grp)
   from(
        select id
               ,customer_id
               ,is_true
               ,max(is_rank) over(partition by customer_id order by id) max_grp
          from (select id,customer_id,is_true
                       ,case when is_true=1 and lag(is_true) over(partition by customer_id order by id)=0 
                              or  lag(is_true) over(partition by customer_id order by id) is null then
                             DENSE_RANK() over(partition by customer_id order by id)
                        end as is_rank
                   from dbo.t
                 )x
      )y
```